# Concatenation from 2 methods in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, numberpicker

I am trying to take the value of an integer newVal (string) from one method, to use in the toast message in another method.
Although I have declared this int newVal at the top of the class, it is only showing a 0 in the toast nessage. (And even that maybe the int value).
Everything else ie checkbox results are showing up OK, but the number picker result, newVal isn't. Yet it looks correct.
Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with the toast message ie adding/finding the value of newVal??
Many thanks in advance!

Below is the MainActivity and activity_main.xml..

```
    package com.example.frytest;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.NumberPicker;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int newVal;
    private TextView tv;
    Button button;
    Button btnDisplay;
    private CheckBox chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupUI();


    addListenerOnChkIos();

    }

    public void setupUI()
    {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvId);

        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.npId);

        np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener()
        {
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
                int newVal)
            {
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
            }        
        });

        np.setMaxValue(12);
        np.setMinValue(0);


    }

    public void addListenerOnChkIos() {

        chk1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk1);
        chk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk2);
        chk3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk3);
        chk4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk4);


        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              //Run when button is clicked
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            result.append("Haddock-Large : ").append(chk1.isChecked());
            result.append("\nHaddock-Medium : ").append(chk2.isChecked());
            result.append("\nHaddock-Small :").append(chk3.isChecked());
            result.append("\nKids Corner : ").append(chk4.isChecked());


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, result.toString() + " " + String.valueOf(newVal),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
        });
    }



    }

activity_main.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.frytest.MainActivity" 
    android:background="#e83a43"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



     <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/chk1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Haddock(large)   £4-40"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <NumberPicker android:id="@+id/npId"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:layout_width="40dp"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:background="#ffffff" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="20sp" />      




         <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/chk2"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

             android:text="Haddock(Medium)   £3-00"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/chk3"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Haddock(Small)   £2.30"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />


         <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/chk4"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Chips   £1-40"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:textSize="20dp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling a method that writes a value to newVal so it would be initialized with 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

it because you never change the value of newValue, when `onValueChange` is invoked

```
 public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, 
            int newVal)
 {
      MainActivity.this.newVal = newVal;
      tv.setText(String.valueOf(newVal)); 
 }
```

or you could simply read it back from the `TextView` (`tv`), before showing the `Toast`

Comment: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, tv.getText().toString() + " " + result.toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Next question - how would I use i=0, i++ to iterate through chk0, chk1 onwards so I'm not repeating this code up to chk50?? I'm used to C++ iteration, not Java.

Comment: The idea - in my larger App - is to check if checkbox of a menu is checked, and also the related quantity (number picker int NewVal value, of course.) So I don't want to repeat above code for all 50 chk0..chk50 checkboxes and npId number pickers..

Comment: In other words, 1 Checkbox and its related number picker - so toast would say eg 1 x Haddock (Small)

Comment: Sorry - clicked too early - meant to say eg 1 x Haddock(Small), 3 x (Haddock(Medium), 2 x Haddock(Large).